# Loan repayment and level amortization

Tags: solution-verification, finance

Tyson wants to pay off some debt and decides to borrow money from James. He takes a $25$-year loan that is to be paid off in level amortization payments at the end of each **quarter**. If the nominal annual interest rate is $12$%, convertible **monthly**, and the principal reduction in the $29$th payment is $1860$, find the amount of principal reduction in the $61$st payment.

My attempt:

The nominal yearly interest is $12$% so the month effective interest rate is $\frac{12}{12} = 1$%. The quarterly effective interest, $j$ is

$$(1 + j)^{4} = (1 + 0.01)^{12}$$

$$j = 0.030301$$

Let us let $P$ be the amount borrowed in the beginning. This must be satisfied:

$$K \cdot a_{100, j} = P$$

, where $K$ is the level payment amount.

The payment amount from the $29$th payment is $1860$ so we have

$(P - S_{29}) - (P - S_{28}) = S_{28} - S_{29} = U_{29}$, where $S_n$ is the outstanding loan balance after the $n$th payment and $U_n$ is the reduction from the payment.

$K \cdot a_{72, j} - K \cdot a_{71, j} = 1860$

$K (\frac{1 - 1.030301^{-72}}{0.030301} - \frac{1 - 1.030301^{-71}}{0.030301}) = 1860$

$K = \frac{1860}{29.1552 - 29.0386}$

$K = 15956.20656$

Using $K$ we can find $P$:

$P = K \cdot a_{100, j} = 15956.20656 \cdot \frac{1 - 1.030301^{-100}}{0.030301} = 499979.1373$

The amount of principal reduction in the $61$st payment would be

$U_{61} = (P - S_{61}) - (P - S_{60}) = S_{60} - S_{61} = K \cdot a_{40, j} - K \cdot a_{39, j}$

$U_{61} = 15956.20656(\frac{1 - 1.030301^{-40}}{0.030301} - \frac{1 - 1.030301^{-39}}{0.030301})$

$U_{61} = 15956.20656(23.0027 - 22.6997)$

$U_{61} = 4834.6472$

Is this correct? I'm fairly new to loan repayment and amortization questions so any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: I haven't checked the arithmetic, but the logic looks right to me.  I'd point out that the amount of interest in any payment is $jB$ so the amount of principal is $B(1-j)$, where $B$ is the loan balance just before the payment.  This might be a little easier than computing two successive balances.  Also, the answer is suspicious close to $500,000$.  You might check if that also gives $1860.$

Comment: @saulspatz If you could put your alternative method as an answer below, I can upvote it...

Comment: Actually, I now realize that there's a mistake in this calculation.  You are ignoring the growth of the loan balance between payments.  You can't say that the reduction in the balance is $(P - S_{29}) - (P - S_{28})$; it's actually $(P - S_{29}) - (1+j)(P - S_{28})$.  I should have noticed this immediately, but it's been many, many years since I last practiced as an actuary.  You always have to refer all cash flows to a single point in time.

Comment: Oh yes! My mistake, I forgot to account for the fact that $(P - S_{29}) - (P - S_{28})$ includes interest. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked the arithmetic, but the logic looks right to me. I'd point out that the amount of interest in any payment is $jB$ so the amount of principal is $B(1−j)$, where $B$ is the loan balance just before the payment. This might be a little easier than computing two successive balances. Also, the answer is suspiciously close to $500,000$. You might check if that also gives $1860$.

**EDIT**

Let $j$ be the periodic interest rate, $j=.030301$.  Let $v=\frac1{1+j}=.970590.$  Let $d$ be the discount rate, $d=\frac j{1+j}=0.02940985$  Now, just before the $29$th payment, there are $72$ payments remaining, and the first of them is due at once, so the loan balance is $$K\frac{1-v^{72}}{d}=30.03860564K$$  The interest in the payment is $j$ times the loan balance, or  $.91019978$K, so that the principal in the payment is $.089800210K$
This gives $K=20712.646349$ and $$P=K\frac{1-v^{100}}i=649019.62$$

Comment: Could you could go over your second method? I tried it with the numbers in OPs post but I cannot seem to make it work.

Comment: @Turnipsavocados Sure, just give me a few minutes.

Comment: I'm getting a wildly different answer than you did.  I posted it, so as not to lose the MathJax, but I need to figure out what's causing the discrepancy.

Comment: I think I see it; why exactly does your formula denominator have $d$ rather than $i$?

Comment: It's an annuity due, because the first payment will be made immediately.  Have you not learned about that yet?

Comment: Yes, but why is the first payment made immediately? Doesn't the problem say "at the end of the quarter" which implies an annuity immediate?

Comment: Yes, of course, but we're looking at the loan balance just prior to the $29$ payment, so that there are $72$ payments remaining, the first of which will be paid immediately.

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to this. Doesn't annuity due simply refer to payments made at the beginning of a period? So if the payments in this case are at the end, how exactly does the time at which we are looking at the loan balance result in an annuity due?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123661/discussion-between-saulspatz-and-turnipsavocados).

Comment: After I edited my answer, I found that my answer of $4834.647641$, which agrees with
the OP, still remains the same.  This is because, my error in construing that there were
only 75 payments did not alter that $(61-29) = 32$, which is what my math
was based on.  Therefore, since I could not find a flaw in my answer, since your
answer disagreed with mine, and since I could not find a flaw in your answer either, I studied
both answers more carefully. I'm unsure, but I may have found a flaw in your
analysis.  ...see next comment

Comment: Your calculation of $(30.03860564)K$ is based on
the idea that $K$ represents the payment right at the start of the
$(29)$-th pay period.  You then reason that the interest on this payment will
be $[(30.03860564)K \times j]$, so that the principal in the payment is 
$K - [(30.03860564)K \times j].$  I think this is wrong, because your analysis
is based on valuing the payments as of the day that the $(29)$-th payment is due.
With this eval, none of the payment will go towards the interest, because you
are making the payment on the same day that you take the loan out.
...see next comment

Comment: If that you agree, then your approach, which is more elegant than mine, has an
easy fix.  Simply evaluate $K$ as of immediately following the $(28)$-th payment.
This gives $$P = K(v + v^2 + \cdots + v^{72}) = Kv\left(\frac{1 - v^{72}}{1-v}\right).$$
Then, one pay period later, on the day of the 29th payment, the interest accrued
will be $$Kvj\left(\frac{1 - v^{72}}{1-v}\right).$$
Therefore, 
$$1860 = K\left[1 - vj\left(\frac{1 - v^{72}}{1-v}\right)\right].$$
This implies that $K = 15956.20769.$

Comment: @user2661923 I'll have to look at this tomorrow.  Too late tonight.

Answer (score 1):

I used an alternative approach to arrive at the same answer.

$L = $ amount of the loan. 
$P = $ amount of the payment.

$j = $ the interest rate charged each quarter, where 
$(1 + j)^4 = (1.01)^{12} \implies (1 + j) = (1.01)^3 = 1.030301.$

Let $v = \frac{1}{1+j}.$

Then $L$ represents the present value of the 100 payments.

Therefore
$\displaystyle L = P (v + v^2 + \cdots + v^{100}) = 
Pv~\frac{1 - v^{100}}{1 - v}.$

$\displaystyle (1 - v^{100}) = 1 - \frac{1}{(1 + j)^{100}}
 = \frac{(1 + j)^{100} - 1}{(1 + j)^{100}}.$

$\displaystyle (1 - v) = 1 - \frac{1}{1 + j} = \frac{j}{1 + j}.$

Therefore

$$L = P \left(\frac{1}{1 + j}\right)
\left[\frac{\frac{(1 + j)^{100} - 1}{(1 + j)^{100}}}
{\frac{j}{1 + j}}
\right]
 = P \left[\frac{(1 + j)^{100} - 1}{j(1 + j)^{100}}
\right]. \tag{1}$$

---

At the time of the $(k)$-th payment, the loan has grown to
$\displaystyle L(1 + j)^k.$

This has been offset by payments, whose value at the time of the $(k)$-th payment is

$\displaystyle P[(1+j)^{k-1} + (1+j)^{k-2} + \cdots + 1]
= P\left[\frac{(1+j)^k - 1}{(1 + j) - 1}\right]
= P\left[\frac{(1+j)^k - 1}{j}\right].$

This means that the loan balance, immediately **after** your
$(k)$-th payment is

$\displaystyle L(1 + j)^k - P\left[\frac{(1+j)^k - 1}{j}\right].$

During the period between the payments $(k)$ and $(k+1)$, the interest on this loan balance is

$\displaystyle 
\left\{L(1 + j)^k - P\left[\frac{(1+j)^k - 1}{j}\right]\right\} \times j$

$\displaystyle 
= \left\{L(1 + j)^k j - P\left[(1+j)^k - 1\right]\right\}.$

Therefore, the principal reduction for payment $(k+1)$ is

$\displaystyle 
P - \left\{L(1 + j)^k j - P\left[(1+j)^k - 1\right]\right\}$

$\displaystyle 
= P - L(1 + j)^k j + P\left[(1+j)^k - 1\right]$

Using equation (1) above, this equals

$\displaystyle 
= P - P \left[\frac{(1 + j)^{100} - 1}{j(1 + j)^{100}}
\right](1 + j)^k j + P\left[(1+j)^k - 1\right]$

$\displaystyle 
= P\left\{1 - \left[\frac{(1 + j)^{100} - 1}{j(1 + j)^{100}}
\right](1 + j)^k j + \left[(1+j)^k - 1\right]\right\}$

$\displaystyle 
= P\left\{(1+j)^k - \left[\frac{(1 + j)^{100} - 1}{(1 + j)^{100 - k}}
\right]\right\}$

$$= P(1+j)^{k-100}. \tag{2}$$

---

Therefore,

$\displaystyle P(1 + j)^{[28-100]} = (1860) \implies 
P = (1860)(1+j)^{72}.$

Therefore, the 61st loan reduction is

$\displaystyle (1860)(1+j)^{72} \times (1+j)^{[60-100]} = 
(1860)(1+j)^{32} = 4834.647641.$